# C# generics performance vs interface

Tags: c#, generics

Consider the following C# code:

```
interface IFace
{
    void Do();
}

class Foo: IFace
{
    public void Do() { /* some action */ }
}

class Bar
{
    public void A(Foo foo) 
    {
        foo.Do();
    }

    public void B<T>(T foo)
        where T: IFace
    {
        foo.Do();
    }

    public void C(IFace foo)
    {
        foo.Do();
    }

    public void D<T>(T foo)
        where T: class, IFace
    {
        foo.Do();
    }
}
```

with the following usage:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();

MeasureExecutionTime(() => bar.A(foo), "A");
MeasureExecutionTime(() => bar.B(foo), "B");
MeasureExecutionTime(() => bar.C(foo), "C");
MeasureExecutionTime(() => bar.D(foo), "D");
```

The results (VS2015, .NET 4.5.2) are:

> A: 3,00 ns/op, 333,4 mop/s
>
> B: 5,74 ns/op, 174,3 mop/s
>
> C: 5,55 ns/op, 180,3 mop/s
>
> D: 5,64 ns/op, 177,4 mop/s

I want to know why using the generic method `B` has completely no advantage over using interface in both x86 and x64 modes (like C++ templates vs virtual calls). The generic method is even slightly slower than non-generic interface-based method (this effect is steady and remains when B and C measurements are swapped).

Appendix: MeasureExecutionTime code can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d60f5d09868ed3a00ec00f413f6afb0

Update: I have tested the code on Mono, the results are the following:

> andrew@ubuntu-nas:/data/mono/json/x64$ mono Test.exe
>
> A: 3.40 ns/op, 294.0 mop/s
>
> B: 3.40 ns/op, 293.7 mop/s
>
> C: 6.80 ns/op, 147.1 mop/s
>
> D: 3.40 ns/op, 294.2 mop/s

The generated IL code can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58df84eda906e83c64ce1b4fdc5497fb

MS and Mono generates the same IL code except for the method `D`. Nevertheless, it cannot explain the difference for the method `B`. If I run MS-generated code by Mono without recompilation, the results for the method `D` become the same as for `B`.

Comment: Why *should* there be any difference? The generic implementation has the same conditions as your interface-approach, namely that both instances provided as argument *have* to be of type `IFace`. What does `where T: IFace` give you what `(IFace foo)` doesn´t?

Comment: Generics are not like c++ templates; They arn't compiled to their used forms at compile time.

Comment: Because I expect `T` to be a concrete class `Foo` and `IFace` to be a contract. Why CLR that knows the type at runtime does not generate an effective code?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund, I know the difference. But CLR knows the type when compiling the generic method.

Comment: For info; in my own implementation of this, I see very different results - I get A twice as fast as B/C. I Added a D which was B but with a `T:class, IFace` constraint, and it behaves identically. Running in release console in both 32 and 64 bit, current CLR. Script: http://pastie.org/10914172

Comment: @MarcGravell, The IL code generated for method `D` is very different from `B`.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov the only difference is that it knows the T cannot be a value-type, so it doesn't need to tell the JIT to handle constrained calls; but since the T would have resolved to a reference-type *anyway*, it would have become virtually identically the same bytecode. The difference ends up as is "load the address, dereference, callvirt" (B) vs "load the *value* of the reference, callvirt" (D). They perform the same. I suspect the JIT makes them almost indistinguishable.

Comment: @MarcGravell, check the generated IL code in the updated question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to know why using the generic method B has completely no advantage over using interface in both x86 and x64 modes (like C++ templates vs virtual calls).

CLR generics are not C++ templates.

Templates are basically a search-and-replace mechanism; if you have ten instantiations of a template then ten copies of the source code are generated and all compiled and optimized. This trades off improved optimizations at compile time against increased compile time and increased binary size.

Generics, by contrast, are compiled *once* to IL by the C# compiler, and then code is generated for each instantiation of the generic by the jitter.  **However**, as an implementation detail, all instantiations that give reference types for the type arguments use the same generated code. So if you have a method `C<T>.M(T t)`, and it is called with T being both string and IList, then the x86 (or whatever) code is generated *once* and used for both cases.

Therefore there is no getting around any penalty imposed by virtual function invocations or interface invocations. (Which use similar but somewhat different mechanisms.)  If, say `T.ToString()` is called inside the method, then the jitter does not say "oh, I happen to know that if T is string then ToString is an identity; I will elide the virtual function call", or inline the body, or any such thing.

This optimization trades off decreased jit time and smaller memory usage for slightly slower invocations.

If that performance tradeoff is not the one you want, then don't use generics, interfaces or virtual function calls.

Comment: This makes me clear. Now I believe that the observed effect was just caused by inlining produced by Mono JIT.

Comment: So how does it work when the code accesses `typeof(T)`?

Comment: @Tim: `typeof` is a syntactic sugar for a call to `GetTypeFromHandle`.

Comment: @Tim: I realize I have begged the question. How do we know what handle to pass `GTFH`?  I did not write that mechanism but we can make an educated guess as to how it works. C# generates a `ldtoken T` instruction. Since the jitter knows at the time of jitting the *caller* of the generic method what `T` is, it can choose to generate code that stashes a handle to the value of `T` in a location known to the called generic function. It would be interesting to look at the CLR sources and see exactly how it does so.

Comment: I imagine the easiest implementation would be to pass the handle as an argument under the hood. But yes, it would be interesting to see how it's actually done.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile and look at the IL you will see that the generic version is exactly the same as the non-generic interface version, with an additional type constraint check first, which makes it slightly slower, although the difference is likely negligible in real code anyway. Even the virtual call on an interface makes a much bigger difference, and clean code is usually going to be much more important than a nanosecond here or there.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Bar.A:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  callvirt    UserQuery+Foo.Do
IL_0006:  ret         

Bar.B:
IL_0000:  ldarga.s    01 
IL_0002:  constrained. 01 00 00 1B 
IL_0008:  callvirt    UserQuery+IFace.Do
IL_000D:  ret         

Bar.C:
IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  callvirt    UserQuery+IFace.Do
IL_0006:  ret
```

Generics in .net are not the same thing as templates in C++.

Comment: I have looked into generated assembly code and tried to run the program on Mono. Seems the problem is that Microsoft CLR does not perform inlining even if `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining` is set.

Comment: "constrained" is not really a runtime check; it is a hint to the JIT that helps it optimize the call (callvirt can be replaced with call in some cases), in particular when using value-types. Since the JIT is once for all reference-types, and once-per-T for value types, the *check* shouldn't have any impact - especially as the T is reference type in this case, so the constrained call will actually become a regular callvirt

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you are incurring both Interface constraint checks and generic itself, compared to just passing a interface typed parameter. The difference though is not that big.

Comment: I want to run come CPU expensive code on server (large structure comparison and merge) and 2-3 times slower performance with generics and interfaces is significant for me.

Comment: Yes, direct typing is faster more, but I meant difference between Generic version and Interface version, as I assumed your question is more about that part.

Comment: The question is why CLR does not generate the effective code from IL when knowing concrete types.